# Pages take more than 5 minutes to load

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a problem with my magento installation.
I'm using the M CE 1.7.0.2 
I tried to do a System Backup inside the admin, and I closed the browser page by mistake.
After that, when I tried to access the website again, I got an 503 error.
After some research I've deleted the maintanence.flag file.

After that, the website got up in the air once again, but now it takes more than 5 minutes to load a page.

Anyone had this problem before? How can I solve it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Ouch, according to [this research](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/loading-time-lrg.jpg) your site should make a few dollars per month and the changes should decrease customer satisfaction by a mere 4800%.

Comment: @marius : I feel this question is good and it is not right to close it !

Comment: @programmer_rkt. Ok. I've reopened it. Let's see your answer :)

Comment: @Marius : no in this case I am helpless. But you should really look on the below answer and its comments. Actually I felt JoeyH's comment is right :-) (not on his last point. Because I know who is marius and what's his power (Y) )

Comment: @user1476643, is the issue solved or it remains the same?

Comment: @Marius Thank you for reopening this question.

Answer (score 3):

Some things to check:

- It is possible that the backup process is still running. Log into your server a do a TOP from the CLI.
- Just to make sure nothing is running you can restart your webserver from the CLI

from the CLI at your site root

- Enable your cache:  php shell/cache.php --enable all
- Flush your cache:  rm -rf var/cache/*
- Refresh your cache: php shell/cache.php --refresh all

Comment: Hi, I just saw your answer after 15h. When I came to the website again this morning, I had an 500 Internal Error. What I did was change the permissions in index.php file to 755 (it was 644).
So probably the issue with all that lag was that the backup was still running, or, the server had no more space left because of this backup.
Thanks very much

Comment: I have contacted Stack about your question being put on hold. In my opinion, it is a valid question that deserves a good answer and blocked by someone who took enough time to read your question, but no time to contribute in a positive manor